# Leaflet cluster color based on icons inside

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markerclusterer

I have pins on my leaflet.js map where the image is determined by the status of the object they are representing. For example, online and offline users - online are green and offline are red. I do this by adding a class to the divIcon and then control the images with css.

I have now added marker clustering to my map. What I want to do is determine the color of the cluster by the **majority** of status' within the cluster. My first idea was to do something like this:

```
this.markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        // Use this somehow to filter through and look at the pin elements
        console.log(cluster.getAllChildMarkers());

        return new L.DivIcon({ html: /* ?? */ });
    }
});
```

But unfortunately I am not able to access the HTML elements from the array returned from `getAllChildMarkers`.

Anyone have any ideas on how I might be able to do this? Or a way to get the pin's HTML element?

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is where I create my map pins (assigned to my backbone model's `mapPin` attribute):

```
that.mapPins.org = L.divIcon({
className: 'org-div-icon',
    html: "<div class='org-status "+ org.getGroupStatus() +"'></div>",
    iconSize: [35, 35],
    iconAnchor: [18, 17]
});
```

And here is how I change the class dynamically:

```
$(model.get('mapPin')._icon).find('.org-status').attr('class', 'org-status ' + model.getGroupStatus());
```

I thought that I would be able to access `_icon` from the return of `getAllChildMarkers` like I do above, but it doesn't seem to be there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `getAllChildMarkers` to get all of the markers in the cluster.  Once you have a marker, you can access its class with `marker.options.icon.options.className`.  You can access the html with `marker.options.icon.options.html`

Here's some code that uses underscore.js functions to count the number of markers with each class, find the one that's most popular, and use that class for the cluster marker.

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
  iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {
    var childMarkers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
    // count how many there are of each class
    var counts = _.countBy(childMarkers, function(marker) {
      // class at icon level
      //return marker.options.icon.options.className;
      // class inside html
      return $(marker.options.icon.options.html).attr('class');
    });
    // get the class with the highest count
    var maxClass = _.invert(counts)[_.max(counts)];
    // use this class in the cluster marker
    return L.divIcon({ html: cluster.getChildCount(), className: maxClass });
  },
});
```

Comment: I should have specified.. I am updating the classes dynamically as time goes on. So the className option is actually not being used to assign the class that I am looking for. I will edit to show how I am updating the classes

Comment: You can get at the html with marker.options.icon.options.html and then use jQuery to extract the class attribute.

Comment: That is just the html defined in the options at the begining, I am changing it dynamically - I need to grab the updated html

Comment: jQuery should give you the current state: var mid = $(marker.options.icon.options.html).attr('id'); return $(mid).attr('class');