# leaflet marker color based on value from objects inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

Writing my observing webapp and need to know quickly damaged points of my devices on my map. i am using leaflet maps. So please, give me the direction whether it`s possible to change color of marker so that it will depend on svg object inside this cluster? for example i have some devices which marked as damaged with a red color. can my map show me the green marker here as red when one of my device there is damaged? Many thanks for answers.

My map example:

[image]

```
    <div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Points &copy 2012 LINZ'
        }),
        latlng = L.latLng(-37.82, 175.24);

    var map = L.map('map', {center: latlng, zoom: 13, layers: [tiles]});

    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

    for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
        var a = addressPoints[i];
        var title = a[2];
        var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title });
        marker.bindPopup(title);
        markers.addLayer(marker);
    }

    map.addLayer(markers);

</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. We need to see your code in order to help. Please read [ask] and provide a [MCVE] of your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056750/leaflet-cluster-color-based-on-icons-inside ?

Comment: I am not sure if you can do that, but you can, for example, make a red marker in a separate layer and add in on top of cluster markers to make sure you can see the damaged devices.